# Help on HTML and PHP development tools

Tags: ide

I am new to web development. I have experience with raw HTML (using notepad). But I am planning to make a website for my final year project. I had previously asked a question on its idea, now i need some help with the development part.

Which tool can I use to design the website? Please suggest some easy to use and powerful tools, with which I can have lots of flexibility and scope to make a really appealing website.

Also I want to use PHP + MySQL in the back-end. Which tools would you suggest for PHP (easy to use and powerful both).

Can the content developed with these two different tools (for PHP and one for HTML) integrate seamlessly? I look forward to your valuable suggestions....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: i am looking for IDE's for PHP and HTML... 
any additional advice on PHP programming is welcome...

Comment: Which OS are you using? Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a light-weight text-based IDE, look no further than [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). It has support for many languages.

In terms of HTML and CSS, it's best to stick with a text-IDE, rather than going into the nightmare that is dreamweaver and frontpage.

PHP can be tricky. You ideally want [XAMPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/) installed on your machine to ease testing.

Answer (score 0):

You question is very difficult to answer, because with "powerful tools" come complexity.  In design, there is a good rule:

> Good, Fast and Cheap; Pick two.

This being said, if your are just looking for a simple CMS, Wordpress is pretty nice.  It's doesn't require much programming experience to setup, and allows you to create a simple web page with little effort.

Comment: I just realized you were asking about a IDE, not a CMS.  Wow, i need more coffee.

Comment: Actually, the `ide` tag was my addition. I may have interpreted it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this question is too subjective.  Many IDE/editors have integrated support for PHP/HTML, since it's very common to embed PHP code in HTML.

This article may be helpful.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-ide/index.html