# HTML development tools

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help on HTML and PHP development tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325618/help-on-html-and-php-development-tools)

Hi All,

I am new to development in HTML code,Please suggest any tools to develop HTML code.

Regards,
Raj

Answer (score 2):

Any text editor you can find on your computer is a great start.

Comment: I am sure this is not correct answer.I am expecting some design tool.

Comment: @user581805: With all due respect, I believe it's a perfectly valid answer. You're writing markup, not messing about in something like Photoshop.

Comment: with your palms you can eat soup also, but I don't think you don't use spoon.

Comment: @Sotiris: True, but a lot of professional taste testers don't eat soup with their hands.

Answer (score 2):

[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) studio is good for web development, I currently prefer [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for doing web/js/css/php editing with it's syntax colouring.

Also, if you will be using PHP and MySql development then [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is an excellent choice.  I currently run it off of my pen drive so that I can run it in work, home or wherever.

Answer (score 1):

For something simple you can use your text editor of your operating system and a browser. If you want to move to something more complicated, finding errors, using WYSIWYG and many other things, there are free and commercial applications.

A very popular free editor is  [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). But you can find more [using Google](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=html+IDE&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=).

The alternative is to use a commercial solution, again the most popular solution is [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/) .

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I am afraid to see all above answers.Please guys if you know the answer please resond,instead of discuoraging and downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with Dreamweaver for learning HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the best tool is a PC, equipped with a display, keyboard and mouse. However, alternatives can be used, too (Mac, PDA, ...)